# Store a long value to a variable in Jmeter using preprocessor and print/use the same value in a sampler

Tags: jmeter, beanshell

below are the steps i followed,
1) Added a BeanShell sampler and add a Bean Shell Preprocessor to the same sampler.

```
long c = 25478995L;
log.info(c + " - It is long");
vars.put("c",c)
```

2) I am trying to print the value c in Bean Shell sampler like below,

```
${c}
```

3) But when i see in view result tree i am getting the ${c} instead i am expecting to view 25478995.

Can any one help me please.
Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Hari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you want to store a [Long](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) per se you need to use [vars.putObject()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-) function instead like:

   ```
   vars.putObject("c", c);
   ```

   and later on:

   ```
   log.info("My long value is: " + vars.getObject("c"));
   ```
2. If you want to have [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) representation - you need [to convert your Long to String first](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toString-long-) like:

   ```
   vars.put("c", Long.toString(c));
   ```
3. Don't refer variables like `${c}` in scripts, use `vars.get("c");` or `vars.getObject("c");` instead
4. Since JMeter 3.1 i[t is recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) rather than Beanshell for performance reasons, see [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert long number to string in vars.put method .
There are 2 approaches you can do this

You can use String.valueOf() method to do that

```
long c = 25478995L;
vars.put("c",String.valueOf(c));
```

Or simply you can append the long value to a string.

```
long c = 25478995L;
vars.put("c",c+"");
```

You can follow  [this blogs](https://www.redline13.com/blog/category/jmeter/)  for such information

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below:-

**BeanShell PreProcessor**

```
long c = 25478995L;
log.info(c + " - It is long");
vars.put("x",c.toString());
```

**BeanShell Sampler**

```
log.info("Value of x==="+vars.get("x"));
```